# How to run the btsync service as the local user?

Tags: 14.04, permissions, upstart, services, btsync

I just installed the new btsync package, per [this blog post](https://blog.getsync.com/2016/02/18/official-linux-packages-for-sync-now-available/). All seems well, except I can't add any folders—the service is running under the newly-created `btsync` account. I need to find out how to run it under my local user account.

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/676022/248771), but the context there is Ubuntu 15. I'm running 14.04. Then there's [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/284894/248771), but it's frighteningly sparse on details.

I tried to make sense of the Upstart documentation [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/), but it's absolutely huge and I'm getting lost by about the second paragraph.

Could someone provide a simple step-by-step instruction of what exactly I must do to configure this? Do I need to edit a file somewhere? How would I go about editing that file?

As you can see, I'm not very handy yet with all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been reading about the `systemd` issue and the fork. It seems there's been a bit of a row over the thing. Myself I'm not partial—if I can accomplish what I need, then I'm happy.

This is a friend's older laptop anyway... I'll just wipe it clean and put the latest Lubuntu on it, which as I've discovered comes with `systemd` by default. Problem solved.